# SQL: Insert Data from another database if they don't already exist

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, data-migration

I have two SQL Server databases A and B

They both contain a table named `Users` with the columns `name`, `Age`, `Salary`

I want to write a script to insert the `Users` from database A into database B (if they don't already exist based on `Name`)

So basically I need this in SQL script:

```
Foreach (UserA in DatabaseA.Users)
    If UserA.Name does not exist in DatabaseB.Users
        Insert UserA in DatabaseB.Users
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one way, no need to loop, you can do it set based

```
insert DatabaseB.Users
select name, age,salary
from DatabaseA.Users a
where not exists (select 1 from DatabaseB.Users b where b.name = a.name)
```

There are more ways to do this by using IN, OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, some examples here [Select all rows from one table that don't exist in another table](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#4)

Comment: Thanks I will try this now. one question tho: should it be 'insert into' or just insert? also will this work if there is more column than 'name', 'age' and 'salary' but I'm only interested in inserting those 3? (the rest will be null)